# How can a visitor add options to a menu through text fields?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following drop down menu.

```
<select id="MySelectMenu">
<option value="#">-*-*- Main Accounts -*-*-</option>
 <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
 <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
 <option value="http://www.example.com">Example</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible for me to add two text input fields where the visitor can populate the menu options themselves?

For example, in text field one they input the url for the option, and text field two, they input the name of the option.

So...
Text field one: http://www.randomwebsite.com
Text field two: Random Website

Then an 'Add' button, which would result in this...

```
<select id="MySelectMenu">
<option value="#">-*-*- Main Accounts -*-*-</option>
 <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
 <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
 <option value="http://www.example.com">Example</option>
 <option value="http://www.randomwebsite.com">Random Website</option>
</select>
```

This is the javascript for the current menu, if this helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function newSrc() {
  var e = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
  var newSrc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("MyFrame").src=newSrc;
 }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add id's to the two option labels, and in javascript get their id, get their values, as well as inner text?

Comment: @AdamH - if you can use JQuery . than you can use `.append()` function

Comment: @MrCoder Thanks you two :) Would someone care to elaborate with my code please? Failing that I will do some research on adding id's and values :)

Comment: Ok @AdamH but please make sure you learn basics..these are basics only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Create two textboxes and Add id's to them and also create a button with a onclick function "Add", Then use the following javascript which is nothing but creating the option and appending to selectbox

```
function Add()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
     var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value= document.getElementById("url").value;
        opt.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value; // whatever property it has
      x.add(opt);

}   


<select id="MySelectMenu">
      <option value="#">-*-*- Main Accounts -*-*-</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
      <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
      <option value="http://www.example.com">Example</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
   <input type="url" name="url" id="url">
   <button onclick="Add()">ADD</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm currently learning the very basics of javascript...your help enables me to learn faster, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

`var url=$("#txtUrl").val();
var textValue = $("#txtDisplay").val();
$('#MySelectMenu').append("<option value='"+url+"'>"+textValue+"</option>);`

use this code on `OnClick` event of Add button.